# Cant select required data from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have problem selecting data from database.

Table looks like this:

[image]
So I need to select `item_id` where `item_property_value_id` is eg. 90, 60 and 97

Expectation:

when provided `item_property_value_id` is 90 and 60 and 97, selected `item_id` should be 8.
If provided `item_property_value_id` is 90 and 60, selected `item_id` should be 8 and 9.

And etc.

I can't figure out how to do that :/
Any help would be appreciated.

**EDITED**

Now I have another problem. I need `item_property_value_id` to be between some values. Everything same as mentioned above, but now `item_property_value_id` should be in range.

Eg.: provided `item_property_value_id` is 90 and 60 and in the row with `item_property_id` = 12 `item_property_value_id` should be between 1 and 5

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
  SELECT item_id 
    FROM x
   WHERE item_property_value_id IN (90,60,97)
GROUP BY item_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_property_value_id)=3
```

and this:

```
  SELECT item_id 
    FROM x
   WHERE item_property_value_id IN (90,60)
GROUP BY item_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_property_value_id)=2
```

respectively.

**FOLLOWING UPDATE:**

Assuming each `item_id` can have only **one** of each `item_property_id`:

```
  SELECT item_id 
    FROM x
GROUP BY item_id
  HAVING SUM(item_property_id = a AND item_property_value_id BETWEEN a AND b)
         = SUM(item_property_id = a) /* item_property_ids that are not required */
     AND SUM(item_property_id = x AND item_property_value_id BETWEEN y AND z)
         = 1 /* item_property_ids that are required */
     AND SUM(item_property_id IN (1,2,3) AND item_property_value_id IN (5,6,7))
         = 3 /* item_property_ids that are required 
                 and have the same allowed values */
```

**FROM LINK IN COMMENTS:**

```
  SELECT item_id 
    FROM x
GROUP BY item_id
  HAVING SUM(item_property_id = 1 AND item_property_value_id = 90)
     AND SUM(item_property_id = 2 AND item_property_value_id = 60)
     AND SUM(item_property_id = 9 AND item_property_value_id BETWEEN 95 AND 99)
```

I guessed at your 2010-2014 item_property_value_ids, you will need to JOIN to the actual values represented by the item_property_value_ids to use them properly.

Comment: Edited question. Maybe you could help me with this one.

Comment: @DarjušIlcevič Bit cryptic, does the item have to have item_property 12 or is the range only applicable if it has it?

Comment: if it has item_property_id = 12 (or other) it should apply range on item_property_value_id. Whole picture should look like this:

select me item_id if it has property_id with provided value [and if it specific item_property (could be more than one) it should apply range to value_id which is in same row.]

Comment: item_id is an ad ID. property_id is (eg. Make, Model, Color, Year, Engine). property_value_id is respectively (Audi, A4, Black, 2012, 1.9) and in search I provide range for Year [and Engine] attribute.

Comment: @DarjušIlcevič you should be able to piece it together from the update

Comment: If I combine them should it look like this?:
SELECT item_id FROM item_property_value_pivot
  WHERE item_property_id IN (1, 2, 9) AND item_property_value_id IN (90, 60, 97) 
  GROUP BY item_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_property_value_id)=3 
     AND SUM(item_property_id = 12 AND item_property_value_id BETWEEN 1 AND 2) = SUM(item_property_id = 12)

If yes, this returns wrong answer :/

Comment: @DarjušIlcevič Whaat? You have filtered out the `item_property_id = 12` in the `WHERE` clause. Rewrite the query so that all the property conditions are written in the format at the bottom of my answer (+ remove the `WHERE`) and it should work.. see update. Note the assumption above the query.

Comment: Maybe I described my problem wrong . Here's link with problem described (I hope now it would be more clear)
[link](http://www.writeurl.com/text/j7ch8udzhoer7v3v4p5m/oz2n5gjoqsj31t4fob0u)

Comment: @DarjušIlcevič See update.. that's the best I can do. Anything else should be in another question.

Comment: Ok, I guess now it returns right answer. Thank you very much. For now :)